# Ethminer opencl error clEnqueueNDRangeKernel ( -4 ) and ( -54 )

Tags: mining, nvidia

I'm rather new to the ethereum mining or cryptocurrency scene. I've tried setting up my first miner on a debian 9 stretch desktop. I'm rocking a nvidia 660 TI 2gb card. I've built the necessary tools and were ready to start mining, but for some reason I'm greeted with errors looking as following:

Starting mining for a pool:

```
  ℹ  05:43:49|ethminer  Found suitable OpenCL device [ GeForce GTX 660 Ti ] with 2095906816  bytes of GPU memory
  ℹ  05:43:49|ethminer  Connecting to stratum server eu1.ethermine.org:4444
  ℹ  05:43:49|stratum   Connected to stratum server eu1.ethermine.org : 4444
  ℹ  05:43:49|stratum   Starting farm
 cl  05:43:49|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
  ℹ  05:43:49|stratum   Subscribed to stratum server
  ℹ  05:43:49|stratum   Authorized worker <my_wallet>.<worker_name>
  ℹ  05:43:49|stratum   Received new job #6b37e31a
  m  05:43:50|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:50|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:50|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:50|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:50|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:51|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:51|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:51|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:51|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:51|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
 cl  05:43:52|cl-0      New work: header #6b37e31a… target 0000000112e0be826d694b2e62d01511f12a6061fbaec8bc02357593e70e52ba
 cl  05:43:52|cl-0      New seed #a91b532d…
  m  05:43:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  05:43:54|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00                                           
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Platform: NVIDIA CUDA                                                                                      
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Device:   GeForce GTX 660 Ti  / OpenCL 1.2 CUDA                                                            
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Build info:                                                                                                           

 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Creating light cache buffer, size 35386688                                                                            
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer, size 2264922752                                                                                  
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Loading kernels                                                                                                                
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Writing light cache buffer                                                                                                     
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Creating buffer for header.                                                                                                    
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Creating mining buffer                                                                                                                   
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Generating DAG                                                                                                                           
  ✘  05:43:54|cl-0      clEnqueueNDRangeKernel ( -4 )                                                                                                            
 cl  05:43:54|cl-0      Switch time 4276 ms / 1419642 us                                                                                                                    
  ✘  05:43:54|cl-0      OpenCL Error: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel -4                                                                                                             
  m  05:43:54|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
```

Running a benchmark, either this:

```
  ℹ  05:47:52|ethminer  Found suitable OpenCL device [ GeForce GTX 660 Ti ] with 2095906816  bytes of GPU memory
Benchmarking on platform: CL
Preparing DAG for block #0
 cl  05:47:52|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
Warming up...
 cl  05:47:55|cl-0      New work: header #50c856ae… target 0000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 cl  05:47:55|cl-0      New seed #00000000…
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Platform: NVIDIA CUDA
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Device:   GeForce GTX 660 Ti  / OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Build info: 

 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Creating light cache buffer, size 16776896
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer, size 1073739904
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Loading kernels
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Writing light cache buffer
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Creating buffer for header.
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Creating mining buffer
 cl  05:47:56|cl-0      Generating DAG
 cl  05:47:57|cl-0      DAG 0 %
 cl  05:47:59|cl-0      DAG 6 %
 cl  05:48:00|cl-0      DAG 12 %
 cl  05:48:02|cl-0      DAG 18 %
 cl  05:48:03|cl-0      DAG 25 %
 cl  05:48:05|cl-0      DAG 31 %
 cl  05:48:06|cl-0      DAG 37 %
Trial 1...  cl  05:48:07|cl-0      DAG 43 %
 cl  05:48:09|cl-0      DAG 50 %
0
Trial 2...  cl  05:48:10|cl-0      DAG 56 %
 cl  05:48:12|cl-0      DAG 62 %
0
Trial 3...  cl  05:48:13|cl-0      DAG 68 %
 cl  05:48:15|cl-0      DAG 75 %
0
Trial 4...  cl  05:48:16|cl-0      DAG 81 %
 cl  05:48:18|cl-0      DAG 87 %
 cl  05:48:19|cl-0      DAG 93 %
 cl  05:48:19|cl-0      Switch time 26940 ms / 23940819 us
1049625
Trial 5... 6033837
  ✘  05:48:22|cl-0      OpenCL Error: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel -52
min/mean/max: 0/1416692/6033837 H/s
inner mean: 2361154 H/s
```

or this:

```
 ℹ  05:47:13|ethminer  Found suitable OpenCL device [ GeForce GTX 660 Ti ] with 2095906816  bytes of GPU memory
Benchmarking on platform: CL
Preparing DAG for block #0
 cl  05:47:13|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
Warming up...
 cl  05:47:16|cl-0      New work: header #50c856ae… target 0000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 cl  05:47:16|cl-0      New seed #00000000…
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Platform: NVIDIA CUDA
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Device:   GeForce GTX 660 Ti  / OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Build info: 

 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Creating light cache buffer, size 16776896
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer, size 1073739904
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Loading kernels
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Writing light cache buffer
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Creating buffer for header.
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Creating mining buffer
 cl  05:47:17|cl-0      Generating DAG
 cl  05:47:18|cl-0      DAG 0 %
 cl  05:47:20|cl-0      DAG 6 %
 cl  05:47:21|cl-0      DAG 12 %
 cl  05:47:23|cl-0      DAG 18 %
 cl  05:47:24|cl-0      DAG 25 %
 cl  05:47:26|cl-0      DAG 31 %
 cl  05:47:27|cl-0      DAG 37 %
Trial 1...  cl  05:47:29|cl-0      DAG 43 %
 cl  05:47:30|cl-0      DAG 50 %
0
Trial 2...  cl  05:47:31|cl-0      DAG 56 %
 cl  05:47:33|cl-0      DAG 62 %
0
Trial 3...  cl  05:47:34|cl-0      DAG 68 %
 cl  05:47:36|cl-0      DAG 75 %
0
Trial 4...  cl  05:47:37|cl-0      DAG 81 %
 cl  05:47:39|cl-0      DAG 87 %
 cl  05:47:40|cl-0      DAG 93 %
 cl  05:47:40|cl-0      Switch time 26952 ms / 23952722 us
1048576
Trial 5... 6032328
Segmentation fault
```

I have googled these error codes multiple times, but can't find a working solution. Nor can I think of another approach to hunt the bug down myself.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: No I have not :/